# External users need access to our domain

Tags: email, active-directory, domain, user-groups, security-policy

We built an application that is configured for single sign-on using our AD with SAML. We use Duo for 2FA. Hence, all users in our domain can access that app with their regular work accounts.

However, a few requests have come in where some external people also need to access that app. Developers of that app have stated that they DO NOT want to maintain users through the app itself which is the reason we federated it to our AD. How do we go about doing this?

I do not want to create new users in the AD and give them an account with my company's email address as that will be very difficult to manage.

I was thinking of creating an AD "Contact" instead of a User. That way I can add "jdoe@gmail.com" and put that account in whatever OUs for access, etc. However, someone told me that AD Contacts don't have SID security identifier so they won't be able to log into any resources. Is there any alternative solution that where I don't have to create and manage new users in our AD?

Thanks!

Comment: But how are we going to set that up with Duo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best solution I found was to use a "Guest Account". You create a guest user from the Azure portal, enable a Condition Access policy to make sure 2FA is enforced on all guest accounts. Even though its not Duo, as long as guests are using 2FA, I'm happy. That seemed to be the best solution for this. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you are correct contacts cannot logon but creating a contact is no more of a management overhead realistically than creating a domain user with restrictive permissions (domain users group only), i would go down this route.
Hope this helps.